# MacOS: Unable to run MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I have been trying to run MySQL workbench on my **macOS Catalina 10.15.2** for a long time now. I have been using MySQL from the CLI. But recently when I tried to switch to the workbench, there has been some **issue with the launching of the Workbench Application**.

MySQL server **works well from the CLI**. But whenever I try to open the workbench, it **opens and closes automatically** within seconds. I have tried installing the older version of the workbench and also tried reinstalling the whole SQL server. None of it has helped me so far. I even tried searching the issue, but most issues are related to the crashing of the application or failure of connection with the database.

I have even tried running the application from the command line and also **"open in low resolution"**. But none it has worked for me :/

It'd be very helpful if someone could help me out.

Thanks!

*MySQL server: 8.0.19*, 
*MySQL Workbench: 8.0.19*

Comment: Hi Sahil. It would be helpful if you specified how you installed mysql (e.g. Homebrew). Also did you upgrade from a previous version of macOS or a clean install of Catalina?

Comment: I've found workbench to be buggy in the past, perhaps try SequelPro as an alternative?

Comment: @DonkeyKong I installed it by downloading the dmg file from dev.mysql.com. And yes, I usually update my OS whenever there's any new update that shows up.

Comment: @JonathanClark I didn't know about it. I'll try that out, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Downloading the 8.0.22 version from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ worked for me, (Im using macOs Big Sur version 11.1)

Comment: This worked for me as well! 8.0.23 did not - it's wild that one patch version makes all of the difference.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar problem (the workbench not launching) until I clicked on the link to the version 8.0.22 of the mySQL workbench posted by Hando and it works. I use MacOS Catalina. This is the link again https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Comment: Thanks my king, your was answer helpful, the version 8.0.22 is compatible with my macosx 10.15.6 - catalina  

Answer (score 1):

yes, version .22 worked for me as well. I did get a 'security' error but was able to go into preferences security/privacy, and 'allow' this app which was NOT loaded from the apple app store.

Answer (score 1):

I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and I fixed this issue by downloading MySQL Workbench 8.0.17 and it worked! :)

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/8/file/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.17-macos-x86_64.dmg

Comment: thanks my version is same as yours and works on mine too...