# MySQLWorkbench quit unexpectedly on macOS Ventura 13.2

Tags: mysql, macos

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfnaj.jpg)

I have tried to re-install, but still same error

Comment: Are you using MySQL Workbench 8.0.32? It has a known crash bug.  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109671 The only workaround is to downgrade to a previous version. I encourage you to log into the MySQL bug tracker and click the "Affects Me" button to add your weight to the priority to fix it.

Comment: Please have a read of [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to help improved the quality of your question.

Comment: Even if this is not related to programming: did you try to search for this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792436/mysqlworkbench-quit-unexpectedly-on-macos-big-sur-11-1 contains hints, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864776/macos-unable-to-run-mysql-workbench also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQLWorkbench quit unexpectedly on macOS Big Sur 11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792436/mysqlworkbench-quit-unexpectedly-on-macos-big-sur-11-1)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply that Python 2.7 missing in Ventura OSX. I installed 2.7.11 via the official pkg installer here (https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/) then installed Workbench 8.0.19 (macos) from the archives page and it works :) Woooo.

Peter, Liverpool

Comment: thanks, I am getting this error when I click on my database that I`v created 9/before I couldn't because of the bug and thanks for your help this version is like this): Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306

Answer (score 0):

I just downgraded MySQL Workbench to 8.0.31 from 8.0.21 and it seemed to be working well. Reported the Bug as well (@ Affect me). Thanks

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers. This was already reported in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792436/mysqlworkbench-quit-unexpectedly-on-macos-big-sur-11-1